# Azure b2c custom policy: How to check for accountEnabled in user journey

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Really sorry for the open question,
but I'm new to custom policies and wasn't able to solve this using documentation alone.

I have a custom policy which includes a user journey with a couple of orchestration steps,
and would like to add one more orchestration steps which checks for accountEnabled.

How would i go about that?

Thank you

Comment: Explain your actual end goal, what do you want to do after knowing account is enabled/disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accountEnabled is read e.g. by "AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress".

So once you have read it, there is a ClaimsTransformation in the base you can use:

"AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue"

that is also called by the read.

Or you could do:

```
<Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>accountEnabled</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
     <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
</Precondition>
```

**Update**

So something like:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>accountEnabled</Value>
            <Value>True</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Some exchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Some exchange"/>        
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, what would this step using "AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" look like?

Comment: It’s in the [starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L525) already.

Comment: not as part of a user journey, as far as i can tell... sorry if i'm being thick here

Comment: It's in the FrameworkBase file in the starter pack e.g. "AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" in some user journeys calls it.